# Can an integer variable be substituted in a concatenation ## macro?

Tags: c, for-loop, macros, int, concatenation

```
#define BRICK_HOLLOW(I) brick_ ## I ## _hollow
#define BRICK_SOLID(I)  brick_ ## I ## _solid


struct wall {
    int brick_0_hollow;
    int brick_0_solid;
    int brick_1_hollow;
    int brick_1_solid;
}mywall;


for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{  
    mywall.BRICK_HOLLOW(i) = 20;
    mywall.BRICK_SOLID(i) = 10;
}
```

Expected output:

The above for loop must expand to

```
mywall.brick_0_hollow = 20
mywall.brick_0_solid = 10
mywall.brick_1_hollow = 20
mywall.brick_1_solid = 10
```

But the code just substitutes the int as a string. So I get

```
mywall.brick_i_hollow = 20
```

Which is not defined in the struct declaration and throws a compile error.
Is there a way to substitute the variable "int i" with integer values instead of a string using double indirection?

Comment: you might want specify in your tags which language you are coding in. So the question pops up in this category too.

Comment: No; the preprocessor runs before the main compilation, so the strings it produces are decided before the compiler proper looks at the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ISO C standards defines the translation process as being comprised of distinct *phases,* as per (for example) `C11 5.1.1.2`. In that section, the pre-processor finishes in phase 4 and syntactic/semantic analysis doesn't begin until phase 7.

That means the expansion of your macro has *zero* knowledge about the C tokens<sup>(a)</sup> and what objects they refer to. It *specifically* doesn't know what *values* those variables will have since pre-processing is a compile-time activity while assignment and evaluation of your variables happens at runtime.

---

In this *particular* case, you would be better off having an array which you could index into at runtime, something like:

```
struct wall {
    int brick_hollow[2];
    int brick_solid[2];
} mywall;

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{  
    mywall.brick_hollow[i] = 20;
    mywall.brick_solid[i] = 10;
}
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It understands *pre-processing* tokens but they're a different beast.